# Firebase cloud function error for setGlobalOptions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am a new user of the Firebase cloud function. I am facing an error when I want to deploy the function. It is a simple function for the test.

But I have got this problem each time.

```
!  functions: Your current project quotas don't allow for the current max instances setting of 100. Either reduce this function's maximum instances, or request a quota increase on the underlying Cloud Run service at https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas.
!  functions: You can adjust the max instances value in your function's runtime options:
        setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10})
Failed to create function projects/orbaic-53e08/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld
```

I only try to make a hello function not more.

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const { setGlobalOptions } = require("firebase-functions/v2");


exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting is because according to [Maximum instances limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances#limits) you must have crossed the default limit of 100 for both HTTP and event-driven functions OR you could have maxInstances setting in firebase.json set to more than 100 or something other value which crossed the default limit of 100 instances.

As the error suggests you could specify the maxInstances for the all the functions using setGlobalOptions as follows:

```js
const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2/options");
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// Set the maximum instances to 10 for all functions
setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10});

exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

#### Update :

An Instance is a single execution environment that runs your function code. Each instance is isolated from other instances, so our function code will not be able to access the state of other instances.

By default, Cloud Functions scales the number of instances based on the number of incoming requests. This means that when there are more requests, Cloud Functions will create more instances to handle the load. When there are fewer requests, Cloud Functions will destroy instances to save resources.

For more information you can watch [Cloud Functions for Firebase - Tutorials](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) video series

Comment: that's worked but can you please tell me what is this instanse? how does it work?

Comment: @RmTomal Hi I have updated my answer about your query.

Comment: Thank you very much it solved that same problem for me!